# Selecting Jsoup element with text containing slash

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to select a tag which contains slash inside its own text with the following code

```
Document testDocument = Jsoup.parse("<p>wanted \\ text test</p>");
Elements els = testDocument.select("p:containsOwn(wanted \\)");
Elements els2 = testDocument.select("p:contains(wanted \\)");
```

When I use `p:contains(wanted)` the p tag is returned but when I add the slash to the end nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually here you are defining the testDocument within the Java code

```
Document testDocument = Jsoup.parse("<p>wanted \\ text test</p>");//if you print this, <p>wanted \\ text test</p>
```

So \ you used the 1st backslash is for escaping and the other one is the actual backslash within that string `<p>wanted \ text test</p>`.

But if you are reeding this `<p>wanted \\ text test</p>` from a file, then Java assume that they are normal characters because special characters are already converted.

So here when you try to find testDocument.select("p:contains(wanted \)"), actually no any text will not be shown.

So it's better to replace the backslash to some other character and get the text:

```
        Document testDocument = Jsoup.parse("<p>wanted \\ text test</p>".replace("\\", "/"));
        Elements els = testDocument.select("p:containsOwn(wanted \\)");
        String x = "wanted /";
        Elements els2 = testDocument.select("p:contains("+x+")");

        System.out.println(els);
        System.out.println(els2);
```